# Unable to save uploaded document in file directory [SOLVE]

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, directory

i'm trying to upload file and save it in directory. i only able to save it in database but not in directory. here is the code that i'm using.

```
<?php
$uploadLocation = "document/";


 $uploadMainTo = null;
  $main_image_name = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
  $main_image_size = $_FILES['file_name']['size'];
  $main_image_tmp = $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadMainTo = $uploadLocation.$main_image_name;
  $moveMain = move_uploaded_file($main_image_tmp,$uploadMainTo);


if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES['file_name']['name'])){
    

    $s_name1 = $_POST['s_name1'];
    $s_num1 = $_POST['s_num1'];
    $s_dept1 = $_POST['s_dept1'];
    $s_phone1 = $_POST['s_phone1'];
    $s_lesen1 = $_POST['s_lesen1'];
    $datestart = $_POST['datestart'];
    $dateend = $_POST['dateend'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $purpose = $_POST['purpose'];
  
echo $query = $conn->query("INSERT into book (book_type,s_name1,s_num1,s_dept1,s_phone1,s_lesen1,datestart,dateend,destination,purpose,file_name,status,created_by,update_by) VALUES ('Normal','".$s_name1."','".$s_num1."','".$s_dept1."','".$s_phone1."','".$s_lesen1."','".$datestart."','".$dateend."','".$destination."','".$purpose."','"$main_image_name."','Proses','".$user."', NOW())");
            if($query){
//                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
               
                echo "<script>";
                echo "<script>alert('Booking Application already send to PIC ')</script>";
                echo "<script>";
                echo "window.location.href = 'list_normal.php?id=$user'";
                echo "</script>";
                
}}?>
```

Hi, just want to inform that i already solve this problem by adjusting the system folder properties and allow permissions.

Comment: var_dump($moveMain) exit(); and check what it returns.

Comment: it return this bool(false)